# Unknown Output of C code

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, unsigned-integer

How does the following code give the answer as 2036, 2036, 2036.

What is the output of the following C code? Assume that the address of x is 2000 (in decimal) and an integer requires four bytes of memory.

```
int main()
{ 
   unsigned int x[4][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, 
                           {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};
   printf("%u, %u, %u", x+3, *(x+3), *(x+2)+3);
}
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour as you are trying to print `x+3` with a `%u`

Comment: you've got undefined behaviour there...

Comment: True, it is UB, but it can probably still be somewhat reasoned about.

Comment: @asimes: The UB is tangential to the purpose of the question, not fundamental to it.  The code can easily be fixed, and then reasoned with.  The UB is one which a newcomer to C can easily make.  Remember, not everyone who asks on SO is an expert (yet).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I did not intended to be critical to the OP, I have also asked questions on SO about UB and was instantly shot down. What I meant to say was that no one on SO will entertain UB curiosities (typically) because it is not meant to be reasoned about

Comment: @asimes: I agree — where the question is intrinsically about UB, then there's no point in delving deeper (or very little point in doing so).  So the questions asking "What do you get from `x = ++x + x++;`?" etc are pointless.  This isn't in that category, as I think you'd probably agree.

Comment: I'm not convinced of the this class of questions: 'explain why obviously incorrrect code does this', UB or not.  It gives the impression to the newbs that such an approach is an acceptable manner of coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've just found out, people can be a bit harsh on SO if you don't post carefully crafted code.  To print addresses, use either `%p` or macros from `<inttypes.h>` such as `PRIXPTR` and casts to `uintptr_t`.

Using just `%p`, your code should probably read:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{ 
    unsigned int x[4][3] =
    {
        {  1,  2,  3 }, {  4,  5,  6 }, 
        {  7,  8,  9 }, { 10, 11, 12 }
    };
    printf("%p\n", (void *)x);
    printf("%p, %p, %p\n", (void *)(x+3), (void *)(*(x+3)), (void *)(*(x+2)+3));
    return 0;
}
```

Now you have defined behaviour, though the values won't be convenient like 2000 and 2036.

However, `x+3` is the address of the fourth array of 3 `int` after the start of the array, so assuming `sizeof(int) == 4` as stated, that is 36 bytes after the start of `x` — 2036 if `x` is at 2000.

`*(x+3)` is the address of the start of the fourth array; that is at 2036 under the same assumptions.

`*(x+2)+3` adds 3 to the address of the third array of 3 `int` and then adds 3 more to it.  That too ends up 36 bytes after the start of `x`, or at 2036 if `x` is at 2000.

On my 64-bit machine, the output reads:

```
0x7fff5800a440
0x7fff5800a464, 0x7fff5800a464, 0x7fff5800a464
```

Hex 0x24 is 36 decimal, of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
   2000  4   8  12  16  20  24  28   32  36  40  44  48
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
     | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10| 11| 12|
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   x {                                                } size = 48
      {   x[0]  } {   x[1]  } {   x[2]  } {   x[3]  }   size = 12 * 4

x = 2000
x + 3 = &x[3] = 2000 + 3 * ( 3 * 4) = 2036
                       ^    ^-----^ size of int[3]
                      index
*(x+2) + 3 = &x[2] + 3 off = 2000 + 2 * (3 * 4) + 3 * 4 = 2036
```

Althout address of `x` and `x[0]` are same there types (and thus sizes) are different.

---

You should add `return 0` in the end of your `main` function. Also your print statement should look as:

```
printf("%p, %p, %p\n", (void *)(x+3), (void *)*(x+3), (void *)(*(x+2)+3));
/*      ^^  ^^  ^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^   ^  ^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^        ^ */
```

For a well defined bahviour.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: As Jonathan Leffler pointed out, I should have cast to `(void*)` before printing `%p`

Perhaps this will clarify what is going on in terms of memory addressing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int x[4][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};

    // Output: Address, 1
    printf("%p, %u\n", (void*)(x),      **x);

    // Output: Address + 12, 4
    printf("%p, %u\n", (void*)(x+1),    **(x+1));

    // Output: Address + 24, 7
    printf("%p, %u\n", (void*)(x+2),    **(x+2));

    // Output: Address + 4, 2
    printf("%p, %u\n", (void*)((*x)+1), *(*(x)+1));

    return 0;
}
```

- `**x` is what should be used to get `x[0][0]`
- `**(x+1)` is what should be used to get `x[1][0]`
- `**(x+2)` is what should be used to get `x[2][0]`
- `*(*(x)+1)` is what should be used to get `x[0][1]`

For additional clarity:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int x[4][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};

    printf("%p, %u\n", (void*)(x),      **x);       // Output: Address, 1
    printf("%u\n",                      x[0][0]);   // Output: 1

    printf("%p, %u\n", (void*)(x+1),    **(x+1));   // Output: Address + 12, 4
    printf("%u\n",                      x[1][0]);   // Output: 4

    printf("%p, %u\n", (void*)(x+2),    **(x+2));   // Output: Address + 24, 7
    printf("%u\n",                      x[2][0]);   // Output: 7

    printf("%p, %u\n", (void*)((*x)+1), *(*(x)+1)); // Output: Address + 4, 2
    printf("%u\n",                      x[0][1]);   // Output: 2

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strictly strictly you should cast the pointers to `(void *)` before printing with `%p`.  It's unlikely to be an actual problem on current machines, but I learned C on a machine where the value of the `char *` address for a memory location was different from the `int *` address for the same memory location (in the days before there was `void *`, I might add — which tells you it was a long time ago — so `char *` was the 'universal pointer').

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, To be honest I was not aware of that at all. I am curious, in what case could that make a difference on the machine you learned on?

Comment: IIRC, if you printed the `char *` address for a memory location as hex, you'd get a value such as 0x80049268; if you printed the `int *` address for the same memory location, you'd get a value 0x00049268.  This was long enough ago that we were delighted when we got an extra 1 MiB of memory (doubling the memory on the machine).  It meant that programs had 1.25 MiB to use instead of just 0.25 MiB since the o/s took up about 0.75 MiB.  So, using the high bit of a 32-bit address to indicate that it was a byte address instead of a word address wasn't a problem; there were lots of unused bits.

Comment: There might also have been a 'factor of 2' in the hex; I don't recall now (and it might have been a slightly different way of coding things).  But there was a difference.  It was a horrid bug not to declare `extern char *malloc();` before using it (and this was in the days before there was a `<stdlib.h>` to declare it).  You learn to be careful in such an environment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Wow, I am glad I learned C three years ago... frankly how `int*` does not give 0x80049268 is still not clear to me. I am assuming "word" in that context is 16 bits as opposed to byte being 8 bits? Even if that is true I still don't see where the difference in addresses comes from

Comment: It was a word-oriented machine (yes, 16-bit words). So the regular addresses were all 16-bit reads. Thinking about it again, I think the top two bits were used for byte addressing, one to indicate that it was a byte address and the other to indicate whether it is the odd or even byte that was selected. So it might have been that you got 0xC0049268 for the byte one beyond 0x80049268. It was also a machine where wizards could reprogram the microcode, adding to the instruction set. The compiler knew what to do; as long as you were religious in casting the result of `malloc()` et al, it worked.

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, my memory of 1983-86 is a bit fuzzy now.  The machine was an [ICL Perq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PERQ).

Answer (score -1):

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
unsigned int x[4][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};

```
printf("%u , %u , %u, %u", x, *x, **x, *x+1);

return 0;
```

}

Just think there is a 2d array here, and the starting address is 1000.
So now when you print a(array) with %u it will print 1000. I hope this is clear. Cause a holds the array address.
Now when you try to print *a it will print 1000 , because a(array) is pointing to the whole array, now when you try to dereference it ,it will point to the first row  , okay. then if you again dereference it , it will point to the first element. As it is 2d array we need to deference two times...thats the logic...thanks. It took me two days to understand this upvote if you like. Try to run the program to get indepth understanding.

Comment: This is wrong. `x` is an array, not a pointer. `*x` works because the array name is functionally equivalent to a pointer. But `**x` behaves different when `x` is an array of `int[][3]` than when it is an actual pointer like `int**`.